# не найден хедер при компиляции в linux, openssl

Tags: linux, c, gcc, include, openssl

Возникла следующая проблема.
Мне необходимо проанализировать работу части проекта OpenSSL, а именно, той части, что занимается вычислением `sha256` с помощью утилиты `perf` в рамках университетского проекта. Я предполагаю (являясь не очень опытным программистом Си), что мне достаточно найти в сорсах OpenSSL исходный код `sha256`, скомпилировать его и подать на вход утилите.

**(Если я тут неправ, то подскажите, пожалуйста, как мне поступить)**

Ubuntu, 16.04, установил OpenSSL (скачал с гита исходный код и выполнил `./config; make; make test; make install`). Хочу скомпилировать отдельно файл `sha256.c`. Захожу в папку, куда 'собрал' OpenSSL, ввожу `find -iname "sha256.c"`. Выводит путь
`./crypto/sha/sha256.c`. После этого в папке `sha` непосредственно ввожу
`gcc -o sha256 sha256.c`
gcc говорит об ошибке, что мол не видит файла `internal/md32_common.h`. Нахожу этот файл в папке `/crypto/include/internal/md32_common.h`. Изменяю команду на следующую:

```
gcc -o sha256 sha256.c -L /Desktop/CodeC/OpenSSL_sourceCode/openssl-master/crypto/include/internal md32_common.h
```

Высвечивается следующая ошибка:

```
md32_common.h: No such file or directory
```

Хотя этот файл там точно есть. Помогите понять, что я делаю не так?

Comment: А зачем вы сам файл `md32_common.h` в команде пишете? Вам надо только указать директорию `-I/Desktop/CodeC/..../internal`

Comment: @mkkik, к сожалению, на это компилятор говорит `fatal error: internal/md32_common.h: No such file or directory`

Comment: `gcc -o sha256 sha256.c -I/Desktop/CodeC/OpenSSL_sourceCode/openssl-master/crypto/include`

Comment: @mkkik, аналогичная ошибка. Я могу добавить к вопросу скрин.

Comment: так объектный файл уже скомпилирован. где именно — см. лог сборки. у меня —  в файл `crypto/sha/sha256.o`. в логе и команда приводится (выполняется она в том же каталоге, где и Makefile находится).

Comment: @alexanderbarakin, в том-то и дело, что я его сразу нашёл и вбил `gcc sha256.o -o sha256`, но он там выдал кучу `underfined reference`. Могу к посту прикрепить.

Comment: так далеко не из всякого объктного файла можно «просто так» скомпилировать какую-нибудь программу. подозреваю, что вам требуется что-то совсем другое, и вы [пытаетесь это что-то совсем другое получить совсем не тем способом](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/709/178576).

Comment: @alexanderbarakin, я Вас понял. Сейчас поясню свою проблему более обстоятельно и то, что я, собственно говоря, хочу сделать.

Comment: совершенно непонятно, что именно вы подразумеваете под словом «анализировать» (вероятно, вы и сами не очень это поняли, и вам следует попросить уточнения у того, кто дал вам задание), но получить sha256-сумму файла с помощь программы *openssl* можно командой: `openssl sha256 /путь/к/файлу`

Comment: @alexanderbarakin, к примеру, запустив `perf record -e cpu-clock,faults ./sha256` я бы получил, сколько времени работает программа, где проблемные места и др. Можно ли то, что Вы показали, засунуть в `perf`? Там ведь в конце каждой команды `./EXECUTABLE_FILE`.? Или можно как-то создать процесс, в котором запущено вычисление хеша и уже номер этого процесса подать на вход `perf`?

Comment: `perf record ...` — здесь `record` — это какая-то программа или опция какой-то особой версии программы `perf`. вот и смотрите документацию либо к тому либо к другому.

Comment: @alexanderbarakin, хорошо, я Вас понял, спасибо.